# Difference between npm install <package> and npm install <package>@latest

Tags: npm, npm-install

What is the difference between `npm install <package>` and `npm install <package>@latest`?

I see many installations instructions around that mentions `@latest` but I couldn't figure out the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@latest` means install the latest available version. It can be useful when you want to update the already installed version to the latest.

For example your have the following package in package.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "some-package": "^1.2.3"
  }
}
```

And there is a new version 2.1.0 available. To install it you can use `npm i some-package@latest`

Comment: it means that simply `npm i some-package` would not install `2.1.0` because it is a major version change, right?

Comment: I mean, it's not yet clear by your answer what's the difference

Comment: In my example I shown the situation, when you already have installed package (you installed it in the past), and now you want to update it to the latest version.

Comment: I know, but what happens if you type again `npm install package` considering that you have a new version?

Comment: If the package is already installed (no matter what version), nothing will happened.

Comment: Actually I think `npm install <package>` updates the package according to semver

Comment: No, I just checked, npm returns a message `up to date, audited <X> packages in 829ms` and that's all. No matter what semver set for the package in package.json.